# Angular Js - Exclude an element from ng-blur

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, onblur

In my application, I have created a custom directive for building a **X** icon at the end of the text box and on click of that, the entire content will be cleared.
The code is

```
angular.module(appName).directive('clearText', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {      
            elem.wrap('<div class="search-wrapper"></div>');
            elem.after('<button class="close-icon" type="reset" id="closeicon" > X </button>');         
        }
    };
}]);
```

The problem is, in the text box where the directive is called, there is another function triggered on `ng-blur` event. I dont want ng-blur function to be triggered if the `X` icon is clicked.

```
<input type="text" ng-blur="getStore($event)" clear-text ng-model="changestore.newStoreId" >
```

Comment: can you add a `ng-click="$event.preventDefault()"`?

Comment: to which element ? button ?

Comment: yea to your directive. if that does not work, you can try a work arround with another condition on your ng-blur, that is activated when clicking on the reset button. and then setting the conditon back when the field is changed. something like `<input ng-dirty="reset = false" ng-blur="if(!reset) getStore()"><button class="close-icon" type="reset" id="closeicon" ng-click="reset = true"> X </button>`

Comment: the `ng-dirty` allow the field to change the value reset to false, so if you trigger the `ng-blur` it pass, since it check for reset to be false. And the reset button change the reset variable to true so it wont trigger the ng-blur